# not able to remove pause/play button when other video is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have added three videos to webpage,  I have added code such that when I single click on a video play /pause buttons appear. I am struggling to figure out how to remove pause/play button from the videos I have not currently clicked.
Also I don't understand why video disappears when I double-click on a video.

Also I am using a bad way way to add to add buttons when I click on a button,
I did it like that(`` elem.innerHTML = `<video class="video" > .........  `;
) `` so that multiple buttons are not added, can you suggest a simpler way to do that.

```html
<body>
        <header class="head">
            VIDEO PLAYER
        </header>


        <div id="videos">
            <div id="video1">
                <video class="video"  >
                    <source src="https://www.videvo.net/videvo_files/converted/2018_04/preview/180301_06_A_CityRoam_03.mp420186.webm">
                </video>
            </div>

            <div id="video2">
                <video class="video" >
                    <source src= "https://www.videvo.net/videvo_files/converted/2016_01/preview/Forest_15_2_Videvo.mov92730.webm">
                </video>
            </div>

            <div id="video3">
                <video class="video">
                    <source src="https://www.videvo.net/videvo_files/converted/2016_09/preview/160820_125_NYC_OutOfFocusCarLights5_1080p.mp444096.webm">
                </video>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="video.js"></script>
    </body>
```

```js
window.onload = init;

function init() {
    var frame1 = document.querySelector('#video1');

    frame1.innerHTML += ' <br> <button id="play">play </button> <button id="pause">pause</button> <button id="volume-up">volume up</button> <button id="volume down">volume-down</button> <button id="mute">mute</button>  ';

}


//to play another video
var click = document.querySelectorAll('#videos > div');






click.forEach(function (elem, index) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', nextPlaylist);

    function nextPlaylist(evt) {



        var save = elem.querySelector('.video').currentSrc;


        elem.innerHTML = `<video class="video" > <source src="${save}"> </video>  <br> <button id="play">play </button> <button id="pause">pause</button> <button id="volume-up">volume up</button> <button id="volume down">volume-down</button> <button id="mute">mute</button>  `;


        var save1 = elem.querySelector('.video');
        var play = elem.querySelector('#play');

        play.addEventListener('click', playVid);

        var pause = elem.querySelector('#pause');

        pause.addEventListener('click', pauseVid);


        function playVid(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            save1.play();


        }

        function pauseVid(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            save1.pause();


        }







    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my working version of your snippet. I created the DOM structure only once, with all necessary buttons under each video. I made all buttons invisible in the beginning (`display:none`) and I also added the event Listener only once. The event listener is a universal one. Being attached to the parent div `#videos` it will trigger different actions, depending on which element was clcked on:

- in case of a "BUTTON", the textual content of that button is used to either "start" or "pause" the associated video.
- in case of a "VIDEO" the associated buttons are made to show up by setting they style property "display" to "inline".

Please note, that I also got rid of the IDs you had in your buttons. These were not unique and therefore not incorrect HTML.

```js
window.onload = init;
function init() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.video').forEach(v=>{
      v.closest('div').innerHTML+=`<br><span class="buttons">
       <button>play</button> 
       <button>pause</button> 
       <button>volume up</button> 
       <button>volume down</button> 
       <button>mute</button></span>`;
      
    });
    document.querySelector('#videos').addEventListener('click',function(ev){var el=ev.target;
      if (el.tagName=="BUTTON"){var func=el.textContent
        if (["play","pause"].indexOf(func)>-1) el.closest('div').children[0][func]()
      } else if (el.tagName=="VIDEO") {
        document.querySelectorAll('span.buttons').forEach(b=>b.style.display='none');
        el.parentNode.querySelector('span.buttons').style.display='inline';
      }
    })
}
```

```css
span.buttons {display:none}
```

```html
<div id="videos">
 <div id="video1">
  <video class="video"  >
   <source src="https://www.videvo.net/videvo_files/converted/2018_04/preview/180301_06_A_CityRoam_03.mp420186.webm">
  </video>
 </div>
 <div id="video2">
  <video class="video" >
   <source src="https://www.videvo.net/videvo_files/converted/2016_01/preview/Forest_15_2_Videvo.mov92730.webm">
  </video>
 </div>
 <div id="video3">
  <video class="video">
   <source src="https://www.videvo.net/videvo_files/converted/2016_09/preview/160820_125_NYC_OutOfFocusCarLights5_1080p.mp444096.webm">
  </video>
 </div>
</div>
```